# Why would someone want to turn a function into a class in react js

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, class, clock

I've just started learning react js from the official site and there is this step in the tutorial in which in order to make a working clock you turn a function into a class. My question is that since it can be done with a much simpler way, why would someone do that?

Comment: In React, you need a class component when you want React lifecycle methods (or a ref to a dom element). So, the difference is how React uses the function or class.

Comment: When you need to create a component without needing to create a state for it (which is called stateless component) it's easier to create it with a function. But when creating a component which needs a state you will have to use classes to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to get access to all the `React.Component` features like `props` and `state`, [life cycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle), `ref` and [much more](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html), you would need to `extend` from `React.Component`.
You can only do that with a `class` (in `ES6`)

**Edit**

> Just one thing, you can access to props too declaring a function

This is not true actually, stateless components are just functions that returns `jsx`. they are normal, regular functions that accepts parameters.
We sometime use the `props` key word as a parameter just as a habit  or convention but you can use whatever key word you want.

Example:

```js
const MyHeader = (myParams) => (
  // no props here
  <h2>{myParams.value}</h2> 
);

class MyApp extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const {message} = this.props; // i get access to this.props as i extended React.Component
    return(<MyHeader value={message} />);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp message="Hello!" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Just one thing, you can access to props too declaring a function.

Comment: no you can't as there is no `props` in functions only regular normal parameters. we call it `props` as convention when you pass it to the JSX element but inside your function component they are just normal parameters like any other function receives.